# Laravel Admin LTE unable to load css, js files from vendor package

Tags: php, laravel, adminlte

I have an laravel(5.7) application which use Admin LTE package for Admin dashboard it was working fine few days ago as there was an issue with server which was fixed but unable to load any css,js file from vendor package.

The application hosted on VPS server and directory structure is like:

- home/user/public_html
- home/user/myapp

Note: myapp directory contains all the laravel app directory and files.

[image]

I have try below solutions:

- Update the composer package with composer install/composer update
- Check with application permissions Dir(755) and File(644)
- I have also tried to update the backup of entire application.

It seems like server is unable to locate those files.

**UPDATE**

Note: I have created a replica on same server with different domain and it is working fine over there but it's not working on this account.

The SSL was installed for this account this was the only change after that this issue was reported. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

This is a live application running in PROD.

I did not understand what I am missing?

Comment: Re-install your application fresh. If the old installation recipe does not work again, it was incomplete and you need to fix your documentation. As this is a server under your control, there is little we can do about it. This is also why I often suggest to not run composer on the server, it does not belong there and things can easily break.

Comment: Also follow the recommendation of Laravel itself on how to configure the webserver / where and how to place files especially in hindsight of the public folder. ( /public_html /myapp looks wrong from distance.)

Comment: @hakre I have updated my question and provide more details about what else I have tried and seems like there was confusion about directory structure.